# how to write a multi-command cronjob on a raspberry pi or any other unix system

Tags: python, linux, unix, cron, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a cron script in python 3 so I had to setup a virtual environment (if there is an easier way, please let me know) and in order to run the script I need to be in the script's parent folder as it writes to text files there. So here is the long string of commands I have come up with and it works in console but does not work in cron (or I can't find the output..)

*I can't type the 5 asterisks without it turning into bullet points.. but I have them in the cron tab.*

> cd usr/local/sbin/cronjobs && . virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/activate
>   && cd csgostatsbot && python3 CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py && deactivate

Comment: You could write a shell script ans run these file from it.

Comment: what difference would it make?

Comment: what exactly do you want?

Comment: to run a script in python3. thats it. :/ it became so complicated because the script isnt compatable to python 2.7 which is the default python on my pi

Comment: install python3 on your pi. no?

Comment: I did but I cant install a module into it unless I do some virtual environment stuff. If you know how to install a module into python3 let me know.. or how to make it default python.. I'm new to unix but not new to computers.

Comment: You intuition is correct, you've definitely grabbed the wrong endof the stick at some point. You probably want to install the OS's pre-compiled python3. Which Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: And tell us about the module that you want to install. Did your org create it? Is it a standard module? Also, what do you mean "I cant install a module into it"? How did you try? What happened that made you think you couldn't?

Comment: when I used pip it would install the module (praw) to python2.7 not 3

Comment: @Duck - then you may have used the wrong pip. See my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you may have a stray `.` in there that would likely cause an error in the command chain.

Try this:

> cd usr/local/sbin/cronjobs && virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/activate
>   && cd csgostatsbot && python3 CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py && deactivate

Assuming that the *virtualenv* directory is in the *cronjobs* directory.

Also, you may want to skip the activate/deactivate, and simply run the *python3* interpreter right out of the *virtualenv*. i.e.

> /usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/python3 /usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/csgostatsbot/CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py

**Edit in response to comments from OP:**

The *activate* call is what activates the virtualenv. Not sure what the `.` would do aside from cause shell command parsing issues.

Both examples involve the use of the *virtualenv*. You don't need to explicitly call *activate*. As long as you invoke the interpreter out of the *virtualenv*'s directory, you're using the *virtualenv*. *activate* is essentially a convenience method that tweaks your *PATH* to make *python3* and other bin files refer to the *virtualenv*'s directory instead of the system install.

**2nd Edit in response to add'l comment from OP:**

You should redirect *stderr*, i.e.:

> /usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/python3
>   /usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/csgostatsbot/CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py >
>   /tmp/botlog.log 2>&1

And see if that yields any additional info.

Also, 5 asterisks in *cron* will run the script every minute 24/7/365. Is that really what you want?

**3rd Edit in response to add'l comment from OP:**

If you want it to always be running, I'm not sure you really want to use cron. Even with 5 asterisks, it will run it once per minute. That means it's not always running. It runs once per minute, and if it takes longer than a minute to run, you could get multiple copies running (which may or may not be an issue, depending on your code), and if it runs really quickly, say in a couple seconds, you'll have the rest of the minute to wait before it runs again.

It sounds like you want the script to essentially be a *daemon*. That is, just run the main script in a `while (True)` loop, and then just launch it once. Then you can quit it via `<crtl>+c`, else it just perpetually runs.

Comment: the . is for activating the virtual environment but I will try this instead

Comment: Can't run without the virtual env as I have a module installed that doesn't work without it.

Comment: It seems to work fine in console but the cronjob doesn't print anything out to my log file although the file is created. `/usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/python3 usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/csgostatsbot/CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py > /tmp/botlog.log`

Comment: thanks, I should be able to figue it out from here, it can't find the file.

Comment: nah I do want it running every minute. 1 minute is shorter than it has to be. It could run every 5 but 1 works just a little better, thanks though

Comment: Okay.. I can't troubleshoot this.. says the .py file can't be found although if I run your command in console it works fine.

Comment: Which one of the cmds are you using?

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/virtualenv/secret_ciphers/bin/python3 usr/local/sbin/cronjobs/csgostatsbot/CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py > /tmp/botlog.log 2>&1` with 5 *. It errors to the log. but works fine without cron

Comment: Re-copy that cmd from my answer. I edited it a couple minutes ago. It was based on the command you pasted in above, which was missing a leading slash on the *Python* file path. (Not quite sure offhand why that would work OK from a terminal but not cron -- that's interesting/odd.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58587/discussion-between-ken-hampson-and-duck).

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands. Hopefully you'll end up with a simpler, more understandable arrangement:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3 # Just in case you haven't already
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ sudo pip3 install praw
$ vi CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py
«Ensure that "#!/usr/bin/env python3" is the first line»
$ chmod +x CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py
$ crontab -e
* * * * * /path/to/CSGO_STATS_BOT_TASK.py
```